# Paticles dont get rendered, only the emitter

Tags: rendering, animation, particles

I want to render a scene from a simulation that involves a particle system + quick explode. My particles get emitted by an object and everything looks correct in the viewport render.

But in the final render (*Render Image*), it only displays the emitter object and not the particles.

[image]

I played around and tried all combinations of *Show Emitter*, *Visibility in Render* etc., but it doesn't work. Also, I applied *bake* in *particle settings > cache*.

See blend file for details: https://pasteall.org/blend/c2afb5f482464b229715ca50ef0b9e3b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disable under *Properties window > Physics > Rigid Body* for your particle object.**
RB is not used in calculation of this sim anyway.

This can be the conflict – blender tries to sim RB and Particles at the same time.

---

*NOTE: It is weird ... when RB is disabled for this object, object disappears from your Collection. You can find it in *Outliner* when you switch from current *View Layer* (outliner type) to *Blend File* (outliner type) ... inside Collections > RigidBodyWorld ... move it back to your collection. I would expect an oposit* behaviour.